# C# -Almacenar tipo de dato 'blob - binary' en una nueva tabla de manera integra

Tags: c#, mysql, blob

### Qué tal, les planteo la situación con la que me encuentro:

Estoy leyendo una huella dactilar desde mysql.
 La almaceno en un DataTable ***DT_1*** comparo contra un ***DT_2***
 y actualizo en este mismo (***DT_2***).

El problema es mantener íntegro el registro de la huella al almacenarlo en la ***DT_1*** para después actualizarlo en la ***DT_2***

*Huella almacenada en BD como:*

> - Blob, Binary  size: 1632 bytes

---

La conversiones que uso son:

```
  //1.
  byte[] arrayhuella= (byte[])DataTable.Rows[i]["campoHuella"];  
  string huella = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arrayhuella);
  //2.
  byte[] arrayHuella = (byte[])DTLocal.Rows[j]["campoHuella"];
  string huella = BitConverter.ToString(arrayHuella).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
```

Dependiente del caso la cadena termina como ***System.Byte[]*** o como *muchos caracteres* diferentes a la cadena original.

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Como guardas la huella?